# Prove that $\int_0^1[f''(x)]^2dx\ge4.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function on $[0,1]$ such that

$f(0)=f(1)=f'(0)=0,f'(1)=1.$ Prove that

$$\int_0^1[f''(x)]^2dx\ge4.$$

Find all $f$ for equality to occur.

Comment: Fourier series can maybe give a solution.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219139/prove-that-int-01fxdx-ge4?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First a variational argument.  Assume that this expression is minimal for some smooth function $f$.  Then let $\delta: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable and such that $\delta(0) = \delta'(0) = \delta'(1) = \delta(1) = 0$ and consider $f + t \cdot \delta$ for a real number $t$.  This function also satisfies the boundary conditions, so

$$
\int_0^1 \left(f''(x) + t\cdot \delta''(x)\right)^2 dx
$$

is minimal for $t = 0$. This implies that

$$
\int_0^1 f''(x) \delta''(x) dx = 0.
$$

Apply partial integration twice to get

$$
\int_0^1 f^{(4)}(x) \delta(x) dx = 0.
$$

Since this must hold for any such function $\delta$ it follows that $f^{(4)}$ is identically zero on $[0,1]$ and so must be a polynomial of degree at most three.  The only such polynomial that satisfies the boundary conditions is

$$
f(x) = x^2 (x - 1).
$$

For this $f$ you obtain the lower bound

$$
\int_0^1 \left(f''(x)\right)^2 dx = 4.
$$

This argument has produced a nice candidate minimal function.  Once this candidate is found the claim follows easily.  Let $f$ be the polynomial above and take $g \in C^2[0,1]$ satisfying the boundary conditions as stated in the problem.  Then $g = f + (g - f)$ and if we define $\delta = g - f$ then $\delta$ has the properties assumed above.  In particular, by partial integration, we know that

$$
\int_0^1f''(x)\delta''(x) dx = 0.
$$

Then

$$
\int_0^1\left(g''(x)\right)^2 dx = \int_0^1\left(f''(x) + \delta''(x)\right)^2 dx = 4 + \int_0^1 \left(\delta''(x)\right)^2 dx \geq 4
$$

with equality only for $\delta'' = 0$. The latter implies $\delta = 0$ since $\delta'(0) = \delta(0) = 0$. So equality only holds when $g = f$.

Comment: Does it matter that we only know $f$ to be $C^2$?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Sure it matters.  It means my argument doesn't apply.  And I have to edit it a bit anyway.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Fixed it... I hope.  :-)